# Windows explorer side panel jumping

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have several document folders selected as favorites in Windows. I have a very organized (and somewhat deep) folder tree in my documents folder. Until a few weeks ago, I was able to hop back and forth between favorites folders in Windows by using the side panel at the left. Now, whenever I click on a link to a folder, the side panel jumps to the folders actual position in my document folder. This is very inconvenient, because I constantly have to scroll up quite far to reach my favorites again.

Does anyone know if this feature was part of an automatic update? More importantly, can anyone turn this off?

Comment: Under Favorites if I click anything it jumps to the actual folder location for me too (for example, clicking on Downloads takes me to C:\Users\UserName\Downloads). Seems to have been that way right from the beginning (Win7 SP1). Can't you add the folders you want to access quickly to a custom Library or under the Documents Library? Those don't seem to jump.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. That might work for me. I'm pretty sure I didn't use to experience that behavior two months ago.

Answer (score 5):

on the windows explorer, click:

Organize/Folers and search options/General(tab)

see the "Navigation pane" in the "ganeral" tab, 
then uncheck the

"automatically expand to current folder"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it was quite annoying. I solved it by going into the explorer's view pane by unticking the "Expand to open folder" option (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of the "Expand to open folder" menu item]

Hope this is useful!